# Business Rules Engine expected performance

Tags: business-rules, rule-engine

How rule engines are evaluated? What do you test to see if it performs OK or not? Milliseconds per single rule execution? Complexity of a rule? If it's "time per rule", what time is considered to be great/bad? Thanks!

Comment: Whoa... You're not even listing what technology you're using.

Comment: .NET. But does it really matter?

Comment: 1) Time : most crucial
2) Complexity handling
3) Space efficiency
4) How complete it is? by complete I mean does it always returns result as theoretically expected.

Comment: @krio. What is "complexity handling" of the engine?

Comment: Its about testing your engine with most complex query with time efficiency

Comment: @krio. If a rule contains 50 equations, is it considered complex? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A major selling point of rules engines are speed. The usually compile your rules, rather than interpreting them, otherwise wouldn't it be easier to just write the rules in a simple scripting language? Rules should not take more that a couple ms.

Comment: Thanks. So, can I assume that the expectation for the execution time of fairly complicated AND COMPILED single rule against some real-life fact object with random data would be about 2 milliseconds on average?

Comment: That's really going to depend on many factors, such as your hardware, and what your domain object looks like, and what exactly you mean by "fairly complicated". If, in your rule, you have no network access and no disk access, and no non-trivial loops, then I would say yes. If you're accessing the rule server requires a network call, than obviously this will have a huge impact. Usually you would have many rulse, each taking a very small time. There's really no magic here, it's just a code generator. How long would the rule take if you had hand-coded it? would be a good question to ask yourself.

Comment: Thank you. That's pretty much what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

It all depends on what you want to evaluate and what's most important to you.

If the pure execution time of a call to the rule engine is most important, you should run tests with rulesets that are designed in a similar way than you expect them to be. The structure, uniformity and complexity of business rule projects can vary widely from project to project. Because of that, it's impossible to make general statements about execution times. Consider a project with 5000 very uniform rules as opposed to a project with 100 complex and interdependent rules. Different engines will handle these scenarios with varying speed. The way a rule engine handles the selection of eligible rules for execution is another factor that determines the performance.

Another important part of a Business Rule Management System (BRMS) is the ease of development, change and maintenance of the rules. Whether or not there are systems in place for rule governance, management of the rule lifecycle, automated testing & simulation or a simplified frontend for business-user.